# How to HIDE paypal IPN through mod rewrite?

Tags: php, .htaccess, paypal-ipn

What's the procedure with hiding an IPN file? Would you just deny access to it via htaccess?

What about input fields?

`<input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://www.name.com/dir/ipn.php'>`

Please share what method you use.

Comment: security risk? or is it safe enough as is?

Comment: it depends on how it is written. Also iirc no one could know exact url for it outside.

Comment: @zerkms could you tell me more on iirc?

Comment: `iirc` == `if I remember correctly` ;-)

Comment: lol! what about the input field?

Comment: oh, my bad... :-S Then no way doing that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're properly coding things, it doesn't matter if a user knows your IPN endpoint. You should be implementing PayPal's IPN authentication protocol to verify that the IPN message your listener is receiving came from PayPal themselves. You'd just ignore any attempts to forge an IPN call.

Comment: See also https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/ppmtsrobertg/securing-your-instant-payment-notification-ipn-script

Comment: @McGeek Thanks for linking that, I couldn't find the exact docs in my quick search.